# Уменьшить длину кода

Tags: c++

На данный момент длина кода - 127 символов без пробелов, табуляция и знаков новой строки. Задача уменьшить длину кода хотя бы до 125 символов, что бы он компилировался компилятором версии c++ 5.0.1.

```
  #include <iostream>
  main() {
  int64_t i=-100,a,b,c,d;
  std::cin>>a>>b>>c>>d;
  for(; i<101; i++)
  if(a*i*i*i+b*i*i+c*i+d == 0) std::cout<<i<<" ";
}
```

Comment: можно условиек в if сократить как `if(!((a*i*i+b*i+c)*i+d))`

Comment: @Evgeniy   Что это за компилятор, c++ 5.0.1, и что делает эта программа? И почему кто-то должен уменьшать этот код?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, функция `main` должна иметь тип возвращаемого значения `int`.

Что касается сокращения числа знаков в теле функции, то, например, можно внести такие изменения. Правда, я не проверял, насколько это сократит общее число знаков

```
int64_t i = -101, a, b, c, d;
            ^^^^^
std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
while ( ++i < 101 )
    !( i * i * ( a * i + b ) + c * i + d ) && std::cout << i << ' ';
```